# Starting Python Shell Window of IDLE for use with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, idle, python-3

Prior to installing ArcGIS Pro 1.3 (I am now at 1.3.1), on Windows 7 SP1, I have been starting IDLE in a Python Shell Window from the Windows Start Menu using IDLE (Python GUI) in the Python 3.4 folder.  I can still do that but it reports that I am using Python **3.4.3**.

However, when I use Windows Explorer and right-click a `*.py` file and choose Edit with IDLE (ArcGIS Pro) the Python Script Window that opens reports that I am using Python **3.4.4**.

In the help for Python in [ArcGIS Pro 1.3](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/installing-python-for-arcgis-pro.htm) it says:

> In prior versions of ArcGIS Pro, Python was accessed outside of ArcGIS
>   Pro through a separate installation of Python for ArcGIS Pro. Starting
>   in ArcGIS Pro 1.3, Python for ArcGIS Pro is no longer required and
>   should be uninstalled to avoid confusion.

which makes me suspect that I should no longer be using or have the Python 3.4 folder under All Programs on the Windows Start Menu.

If I were to delete it, then how would I start the Python Shell Window of IDLE with Python 3.4.4?

Comment: My ArcGIS Pro python install is found at `:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3` (for ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1).  I removed all my other Python 3.x installs (since I wasn't using them for anything other than ArcGIS Pro).  And for what it's worth, my 1.3.1 python install says it's Python 3.5.1

Comment: @Midavalo I think my Python 3.4 is left over from ArcGIS Pro 1.2 and I would simply remove it except that would cut me off from an obvious way to start the Python Shell Window of IDLE with Python 3.4.x.

Comment: Idle is included in the new python install location

Comment: I would go through the Start Menu shortcuts and repoint them to the new install location

Comment: Before I try that (which I am confident will work) I am keen to know whether there is something more OOTB.  Whenever I train people new to Python in ArcPy I find it easiest to just do vanilla installs of ArcGIS Pro/Desktop.  It has been useful to say "simply install ArcGIS Pro/Desktop and here is an IDE ready to use".

Comment: I installed ArcGIS Pro for the first time on a machine today, so thought I'd have a look.  There is no Python found in the Start Menu, other than under ArcGIS Pro > Python Interactive Terminal.  There's no Open with IDLE, or even just IDLE in the Start Menu.  I do get the option Edit with IDLE (ArcGIS Pro) when I right-click on a `.py` file though.

Comment: @Midavalo Those parts all match what I see (except for my left over Python 3.4 folder).

Comment: OMG?! Does that mean that ArcGis Pro having python 'all to itself' is going to cause problems executing python scripts, both arcpy and non-Esri (especially GDAL/OGR)? Historically python 'had a cow' with the space in the path, requiring install to C:\python27\ for 2.7 etc... if ArcGis is keeping it to itself is the CMD environment even aware of the shellexecute for .py files? BTW. I use PyWin editor, I find it much better than IDLE but that's wandering off-topic.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson My reading is that conda is there to allay those fears and abstract complex installs to something easier: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-conda.htm  I think it is just IDLE users losing out in one place due to the change.  Other parts of the change seem to be advantageous.

Comment: That's a relief PolyGeo, I had a brief flash of having to update all my subprocess.popens with a hard path and/or launch all my python scripts via the ArcGis python window - CMD uses *a lot* less memory. I think I've still got a few gp=arcgisscripting.create scripts lying around (if it 'aint broken)...

Comment: Problem is it doesn't install it anywhere logical, so to use arcpy you need to use python from the Pro folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start the Python IDLE GUI from the Start Menu using the ArcGIS Pro Python command prompt.

> Start Menu > All Programs > ArcGIS > ArcGIS Pro > Python Command Prompt

This will open a command prompt window at the current ArcGIS Pro python conda environment.  Typing `idle` at this prompt will open the IDLE GUI.

Comment: Clicking Python Command Prompt gives an Access denied error unless I run it as Administrator but either way at least I can get to IDLE's Python Shell and Script windows now.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of information explaining where paths are and how to launch things in this [post here](https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-8359). It should be the first stop (besides doc) on the changes to Python in Pro 1.3.

In short if you want to launch IDLE, it'd typically be found here now: `"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\idlelib\idle.bat"`
Note - in the post above there was mention of possible problems running IDLE. (So your mileage may vary)

As for an unsolicited personal opinion: *Idle* really isn't great. Theres so many better options out there. Yes, Idle may come bundled up with the installation, but so does Notepad with Windows. Both serve a purpose, but fall so incredibly short compared to freely available options for download.

Comment: It's a shame [that post](https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-8359#) does not itself mention IDLE.  It is currently only mentioned in one of the many comments on it.